# Django Rest Framework Serializer not printing nested relationship

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I've got established a relationship between 2 models: `Order` and `OrderLine`. I've created serializers for both of them following the DRF documentation, yet when printing the `serializer.data` the nested objects don't show.

Here are my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)  

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)


    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

These are the serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Order, OrderLine


class OrderLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    OrderLine serializer
    """
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        fields = ['product_id', 'price', 'quantity', 'total']
    


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Order serializer
    """
    items = OrderLineSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['session_id', 'subtotal', 'total', 'items']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

and this is the view:

```
class OrderAPIViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):

        order = Order.objects.create(session_id=request.data['session_id'])

        for item in request.data['items']:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=item['product_id'])
            total = Decimal(item['price'] * item['quantity']) 
            OrderLine.objects.create(
                order_id=order,
                product_id=product,
                price=Decimal(item['price']),
                quantity=item['quantity'],
                total=total
            )

        serializer = OrderSerializer(instance=order)
        print("HERE")
        print(serializer.data)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

From my REST client I'm posting the following object:

```
{
            "session_id":uuid,
            "items": [
                {
                    "product_id": product.id,
                    "price": 5.80,
                    "quantity": 2,
                }
            ]
            
        }
```

but when the print statement in the view is executed this is what's being printed:

```
{
   "session_id":"4def7bdb-dedb-46aa-9c70-1d9e4f522149",
   "subtotal":"0.00",
   "total":"0.00"
}
```

notice the the items subresource is not being included.

What am i missing?

Comment: You need to implement `create()` at your serializer, see the docs of DRF for more info

Comment: but `create` is needed only when I want to save the data from a POST request, right? I'm this case I'm just performing a serialization within the View, why would I need `create` for?

Comment: then update your question, it's not clear

Comment: please let me know what is no clear for you and I'll update it accordingly. The question clearly states that the serializer does not print the nested data, doesn't mention anything about saving or creating

Comment: that part for posting data made that confusion, dropping it will eliminate any confusion

Comment: anyway I will post my answer later today

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed `read_only=True` parameter to `OrderLineSerializer`. When your serializer's builtin method `to_internal_value()` run, clear data not including in your fields list. For more details: [read_only](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)